# Cannot copy database from solution to local package folder on UWP

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp

I have a database named tryout2.db on the Databases folder in the solution. If on the local package folder there is no such database, then I want to copy it from the Databases folder in the solution to the local package folder.
Code:

```
public ViewModel()
        {
            ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

            if (!localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("defaultCategories"))
            {
                CopyDatabase();
                localSettings.Values["defaultCategories"] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Categories();
            }
        }

        private async void CopyDatabase()
        {
            StorageFile dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Databases/tryout2.db"));
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            await dbFile.CopyAsync(localFolder);
            Categories();
        }

        public void Categories()
        {
            objConn = new SQLiteConnection("tryout2.db");
            string strQ = @"SELECT * FROM DBQUIZ;";
            var s = objConn.Prepare(strQ);

            while (s.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
            {
                Items.Add(new DBQUIZ(s[0].ToString(), s[1].ToString(), s[2].ToString(), s[3].ToString(),
                    s[4].ToString()));
            }
        }
```

Update: Use check if file exist:

```
SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection objConn;
        public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "tryout2.db"));//DataBase Name 

        public ViewModel()
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists("tryout2.db").Result)
            {
                using (var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DB_PATH))
                {
                    CopyDatabase();
                }
}
            else
            {
                CopyDatabase();
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return false;
        }

        public async void CopyDatabase()
        {
                StorageFile dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Databases/tryout2.db"));
                StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                await dbFile.CopyAsync(localFolder);

            Categories();
        }

        public void Categories()
        {
            objConn = new SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection("tryout2.db");
            string strQ = @"SELECT * FROM DBQUIZ;";
            var s = objConn.Prepare(strQ);

            while (s.Step() == SQLitePCL.SQLiteResult.ROW)
            {
                Items.Add(new DBQUIZ(s[0].ToString(), s[1].ToString(), s[2].ToString(), s[3].ToString(),
                    s[4].ToString()));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DBQUIZ> Items { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<DBQUIZ>();
```

I have a problem, that is: every time I copy tryout.db the sizenya is 0 kb and the table is empty.
[image: file]
How to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

The `CopyDatabase` call is happening in the constructor so the `async` calls can't be `awaited`. You should do the initialization later, probably in the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler so that you can wait them.

Currently it is possible you are somehow access the DB before it is actually finished copying and that causes the copy to be unsuccessful. You don't get a exception, because when the call is not awaited, the exceptions are lost as well. Overall, it is a bad practice not to await `async` calls, because you will never know if something bad happened inside.

Comment: can you give me a sample?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so I have to write an answer.

Have you checked the properties of your database file? Try to set the `Build action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`.

I've tried your code and everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, I have set it into content and copy alwat, as in the picture: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U9BZa_qKCeTQ2cz5e

Comment: Have you tried to specify the file fxtension? Because currently you only name it `tryout2`. Can you set it to `tryout2.db`

Comment: In my sample your code worked. But I think Martin is right. Have you tried this?

Comment: After I debug, I found the problem: although the database does not exist on the local package, it always exists. So in if (! LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey ("defaultCategories")) always runs directly on else. How to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the app? Because that is the only mechanism to remove the local settings.

Comment: That is a Little bit strange. I've tested it right now in my sample app and it works as expected. Have you some file opend or have you opened the folder in Explorer while deleting the app? Another approch is to validate if the file already exists instead of using the local settings. What do you mean?

Comment: No, I have closed the file explorer and deleted the local folder.

Comment: Maybe you can try to instead of using the settings to check if the file already exists. For me this looks like the better approach.

Comment: I've tried to use check if the file exist, but its still the same size database that copied to local folder size 0 kb. I update the code